# Retrieve a text value within a div element

Tags: jquery, contains

I have a div element `<div guid="60b758f8-62e7-42cc-ab66-5eca80642f35">100%</div>`
without any id or class, auto generated by the system. I need to get this 100% in a variable through jQuery and then will alert the user with pop-up message.

How can I get this "100%" as text in a variable as it does not have any id or class. Note, this % will keep varying. It can be any value from 0% to 100%. So I was planning to implement "div:contains('%')" function and get the full text then. But not able to achieve it. Can anyone help me out to get full text of this div?

Comment: and what if you write something else with a % onto the page? Why don't you just give it a class?

Comment: I am not a jQuery expert. Thats the reason I am asking for help.

Comment: `<div class="myClass">100%</div>`... `$('.myClass').text();`

Comment: I mentioned it before, this div is auto-generated in DOM. I do not have control over this div. I just want to get the % in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the text method and check if condition for contains.

```js
$("div").text(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($('div:contains("%")').length > 0) {
    console.log($this.text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div guid="60b758f8-62e7-42cc-ab66-5eca80642f35">100%</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Shree. Your answer is excellent piece of code. It worked as expected.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is auto generated, You will need to use the attribute selector:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

> attributeEquals selector
>   Description: Selects elements that have the
>   specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

> attributeHas selector
>   Description: Selects elements that have the
>   specified attribute, with any value.

So it will be something like:

```
$("div[guid='60b758f8-62e7-42cc-ab66-5eca80642f35']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code below.Hope it will works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('div:contains("%")').length > 0){
 var divTxt = $('div:contains("%")').text();
    alert(divTxt);
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div guid="60b758f8-62e7-42cc-ab66-5eca80642f35">100%</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check this code,it will work with whatever auto generated div created containing % in the text

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple div elements with attribute guid and if you need to get its inner text separately then better method is use id or class.
In your case i think only unique thing you are having is attribute guid, so you can search for all div elements with attribute guid.

**Sample Code:**

```
$('div[guid]').each(function() {
     console.log($(this).text());
 });
```

You should also import jquery library at the end of body

**Sample Code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```